# Docker swarm overlay network between subnets

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm trying to set up a Docker swarm cluster with CoreOS. I have 3 hosts with static IPs in a subnet for the managers, and 5 hosts with DHCP in a subnet for the workers. There is a manually configured static route that allows me to talk to the manager subnet. IPs are changed.

```
core@worker1 $ ping 10.13.12.8 # private, static IP of manager1
<nothing>
^C
core@worker1 $ sudo ip route add 10.13.12.0/23 dev eth0
core@worker1 $ ping 10.13.12.8
response from 10.13.12.8
```

This was problem 1, the real problem is much more confusing. If I create a new  overlay network, and add a busybox container to that network, I'm not able to ping the manager nodes from the overlay network on the worker nodes, or vice-versa.

```
core@manager1 $ docker network create -d overlay uber-net
core@manager1 $ docker service create --name test --network uber-net --replicas 8 busybox sleep 1d
core@manager1 $ docker exec -it test.manager1 sh
/ # ping 10.0.5.15 # IP of manager2's replica of test service
response from 10.0.5.15
/ # ping 10.0.5.14 # IP of worker1's replica of test service
<nothing>
^C
```

And it's the same story on the workers

```
core@worker1 $ docker exec -it test.worker1 sh
/ # ping 10.0.5.15 # IP of manager2's replica of test service
<nothing>
^C
/ # ping 10.0.5.17 # IP of worker2's replica of test service
response from 10.0.5.17
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have also used netcat to verify that port 4789 is open via UDP, and 7946 is open via TCP and UDP.

```
core@manager1 $ ncat -ul 4789
hello
core@manager1 $ ncat -ul 7946
hello
core@manager1 $ ncat -l 7946
hello

core@worker1 $ ncat -u 10.13.12.8 4789
hello
^C
core@worker1 $ ncat -u 10.13.12.8 7946
hello
^C
core@worker1 $ ncat 10.13.12.8 7946
hello
^C
```